# How to use jQuery Chosen single select with a textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-chosen

I want to do something  very similar to jQuery Autocomplete but with a `<select>` list and using Chosen instead.

The problem is that I want it to function as an autocomplete text input (instead of having a dropdown that you have to click prior to typing in a query).

The chosen library currently only allows this type of input for multiple selects. Is there any way to do it for a single select?

Refer to the multiple select example to see what I mean:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

Use allow_single_deselect="true" attribute for select tag as:

```
<select data-placeholder="Chose a category" allow_single_deselect="true" class="ec-select mb-2" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
          <option>Technology</option>
          <option>Education</option>
          <option>Sports</option>
          <option>Politics</option>
        </optgroup>

      </select>
```

Thanks!